# Dealing with solutions that end with a new error

Tags: discussion, questions

I was recently setting up some software but I had to come to SO for an error partway through the process. After following a solution someone had posted, a different error was created.

I guess I have two options here.

1. update the question with the new error.
2. mark that problem as fixed and research or ask a new question.

I feel that 2 is the better option. However you lose context that may solve an overall problem and you end up creating very similar questions.

Comment: 2. is definitely the solution, since 1. would invalidate existing answers.

Comment: The second alternative is the proper behavior. Updating the question to change it drastically after it was answered is know as a chameleon question, and it's inappropriate. It invalidates the answers you've already received, which makes those people look wrong or stupid; it can also negatively impact their reputation. If I see such an edit by the question poster, I roll back the edit to restore the question and comment that they should post a new question instead.

Comment: Don’t forget to _research_ on the second problem _before_ asking a second question.

Comment: Hm, if an answer leads to a different error, it doesn't seem to be *solution* to your question. Don't accept it, comment that it's not working. Of course, if the new error is completely unrelated, that warrants a new question.

Comment: It's not completely clear from the information (currently) in this question whether the second error was 1) due to bad information in the original answer or 2) masked by the first error, so you weren't able to notice it until after you'd cleared up the first error. Please clarify this issue, if possible.

Comment: Also, I must admit that this sounds painstakingly much like the approach of someone who should probably get a little more used to the environment he's working on, especially because this is just about *setting up* some software. I don't mean this nearly as rude as it sounds, but: You'd do yourself a favor if you just spent more time trying to solve your problems yourself (this is about wagtail, right?) than trying to let others solve your problems -- you'll learn to deal with new problems faster the next time. If you keep asking on SO, you'll never be self-sufficient...

Comment: To rephrase your question: the answer **didn't** "end" with "a new  error". The error was **already there**. What has happened is that **the question** went into unforeseen consequences territory. It is the responsibility of the **asker** to prepare the question for those, and **not the answerer**.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since it's a distinct error, it deserves its own question.  Do not edit the existing question into something completely different, even if it's part of the same project.  You should avoid asking [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).  Instead, you can provide a link back to the other question for more context if needed.  But really, it shouldn't be too necessary if you write a good question, especially one that has a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

If your questions are *really* related, perhaps it's time to ask a broader design question.  You might be trying to solve a problem that was caused by a different one at a higher level.  These design questions are a bit harder to write, but it might really solve one or both issues you were running into.

As always, you should upvote helpful answers, downvote unhelpful or inaccurate ones, and accept the one (if any) that solved that particular question.

Answer (score 23):

Accept the answer that solved the question then ask a new question.  If there are existing answers that successfully address the original question, do not edit the question to change what is being asked, as that would invalidate those answers.

If you need to provide context, there's nothing wrong with linking to your previous question.  Make sure the new question can stand on its own without the link as well.

Comment: I don't think you should accept the solution on the first question. if the second question doesn't get solved then why encourage others down that path.

Comment: If you ask about an error, and an answer gets rid of that error, and then you get another error, the question about the first error was still answered.  (Assuming of course that the new error wasn't because the answer was actually wrong.)  You accept an answer that solved the question.

Comment: @drawde83: Then you think wrong. You're accepting the answer that solved your first problem. A new, second problem has no bearing on the usefulness of the first question's answer. (And failing to accept the answers that solved the problem you posted (which was the first one) is a) unfair to the user who made the effort to help you, and b) discourages people from helping you in the future (since you *punish them* because you got a different problem by not rewarding their efforts). I know if I help people repeatedly, and they don't appreicate, I feel less encouraged to continue helping them.

Comment: @davidism: Of course it might be difficult to detect whether the new error was caused by the answer…

Answer (score 6):

First and foremost, I'm in agreement with the advice *against* your option #1. I.e. it's inappropriate to edit a question in a way that changes its fundamental nature. This includes tacking a new question onto an existing one.

That said, it is not clear from your description whether the new error is due to a bug in the code provided in the answer, or because your own code has another bug that is revealed after solving the first one.

Note that this is one of many good reasons it's so important for a question to include [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. When you do, an answerer has 100% of the relevant context, and can actually *test* their answer to ensure it resolves the problem and has no errors.

If you did in fact post such a code example, then the problem is definitely with the answer, not the question. That is, the answerer should address *all* errors in that good code example. If they did not, then the answer should not be accepted.

In that case, you can *comment* on the answer itself, explaining that the answer is incomplete and requesting that it be revised so that it fully addresses your question and code example.

If you have not in fact included such a code example with your question, then you have two choices:

1. Improve the question by fixing it so that it includes a good code example. Add a comment to the answer given to explain that they did not solve the problem, and that you have updated your question so that they now have enough context to provide a working answer.
2. Accept the answer given and post a new question (preferably including a good code example in the new question).

Note that in this case, due to the lack of a good code example to work from, it is ambiguous whether your question was really answered or not. It's up to you to decide that, and you should do so based on whether you believe the error in the solution comes from yet another bug in your code, or a bug in the solution itself. Which action you take (of the two options above) depends what source you assess the new error to come from (i.e. your code or the answer).