# Question answered in comments, question changed

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I was recently looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52810269/why-os-startfile-load-the-default-video-player-but-outside-tkinter), and noticed that the question had already been solved in the comments, then changed, seemingly upon the suggestion of a high rep (94K+) user, who I think probably knows the ways of SO more than me.

However, looking at [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300966/dealing-with-solutions-that-e), it seems that changing questions like this is not a good thing to do. On the other hand, the main reason it says we should not do it is that it invalidates current answers, none of which were posted to the question I was looking at.

My question is, when is changing the question the right thing to do (if ever) and why?

Comment: 94k I recognized myself just with the number :)

Comment: Had any votes been cast? Its not just about how many answers but changing the question would also invalidate any cast votes

Comment: @Sayse This is guarded against at least somewhat by users having the ability to change their votes (without an expiration date) after a post they've voted on has been edited.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As long as editing your question results in a *better* question, **and it doesn't invalidate existing answers**, editing it is fair game.

It could be argued that by changing the meaning and intent of the question you could be invalidating answers that were being written but not yet posted.

But what's the alternative? The asker could just as easily delete the question to repost a new one (invalidating those answers in progress as well).

Considering how trivial and uninsteresting the first version of the question appeared to be, the commenter seemed fine in both helping the asker in solving their problem and in producing a better, more interesting question; which seems like a perfectly valid result to me.

Comment: So is it a better or worse option than creating a new question and *not* deleting the first?

Comment: @Artemis It's up to the asker, really. But regarding your question: was this a right thing to do? Yes, it was. Because the changes to the question didn't invalidate any existing answer.

Comment: Editing question to replace with completely new one to bypass question ban is the only exception to such edits (not really the case here).

Comment: There are always edge cases of course, but in general, if you find people are answering the wrong question because your question was not clear or you used the wrong terminology, then editing is not just allowed, but actively encouraged.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov has there been any registered case?

Comment: @Braiam https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375502/what-to-do-when-i-edit-a-stack-overflow-question-and-i-already-have-an-answer :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov "to bypass question ban", that's the case I was asking about.

Answer (score 17):

I'm the user who solved the first question in comments.

First, I want to make it clear that I wasn't sure *at all* that changing `os.system` to `os.startfile` would work in their case (the question isn't exactly a MCVE, with tkinter wall of code all over, which also explains the lack of answers then, or even comment upvotes), else I would have closed that as a duplicate.

Those system calls / windows questions are sometimes hard to answer without being able to reproduce the issue with the exact context. That was a "have you tried ?" comment. Nowadays I tend to try to avoid answering in comments.

Then I suggested the OP to edit their question because it was 1) solved and 2) trivial. Since noone had answered and the question was already "old" (several minutes is old for a python question), no harm done (and no risk of question ban evasion, this question wasn't downvoted)

Of course, that wouldn't have been the same if someone had already answered (and OP commenting/accepting the answer), but in that case, I think I would have closed that as duplicate instead of having one good faith answerer "chameleoned" by OP.

That said, I think that question needs more trimming. There's still too much useless code that makes the question unclear.

(and sometimes SO works in mysterious ways, so I don't claim to know it a lot more than you)