# What to do when I edit a Stack Overflow question and I already have an answer

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I edited a question and It had been already answered but the answer did't help me. So I edited the question and the answer is no longer related with the question.

Shall I edit the question? I feel the correct thing to do is to delete the question, but I didn't becuase that action would nearly ban me for asking permanently.

Comment: Why would you want to delete the question if it received answers?

Comment: Always remember that Stack is there for the people who will Google the same problem you had and find their answers in your question. With that in mind, why would deleting your question makes sense?

Comment: Since you are new to meta, please do not worry about downvotes to your question here. Votes in meta do not affect your account or reputation. That being said, responding to the feedback you are getting to your question is usually good etiquette.

Comment: Do you now have an answer to both the original question and the new one you replaced it with?

Comment: No, the first answer didn't help me, So I found a new way to get by with my issue and now I have an answer that did help me with that "new question"

Comment: That's what I'm saying: the older answer is an answer to your original question and the one you've accepted is an answer to the new question.

Comment: Yes, I guess my case is chameleon question

Comment: Would be right to delete this question then? I'm already banned from StackOverflow, I tried to improve some of my negative questions but I did worst by doing that, now I have more negative reception and if I delete the question is also worst. :/ Shall I shoot myself?

Answer (score 16):

If after asking a question and receiving answers you realize that you need to ask a different question, the proper course of action is simply **to ask a new question**.

Deleting a question that already has answers is in very poor form. (And will penalize you heavily with the question ban algorithm).

And editing a question to change its intent so that you invalidate existing answers very much so as well.

Considering the extensive edits, I imagine you mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52844830/hot-capture-the-text-of-a-label-to-be-used-in-query) question. I'm blessed with a complete ignorance about MS Access, so I wont judge if your edits or your question are any good.

But if this is the one, you should rollback your edits to the question  to the state it was when you got the first answer. That you didn't find the answer helpful doesn't mean that it wasn't an answer to that question.

(Considering this is the question, you have to consider you already got an answer to the old version and another answer to the newer version... so now things are a bit of a mess).

Comment: Sadly, I *am* knowledgeable about Access, and although it's hard to parse, those look like two entirely different questions.  With the number of neutral and negative questions, I suspect this is an attempt around the question ban.

Comment: Yes that was the question I refer to, the first answer is not very related now, So that was my dilemma

Comment: @dirojas just a heads-up: right now your question starts with 'I've reorganized everything then'.... That is a very weird first sentence for a question...

Comment: Sure it is, but I honestly had to reformulate my question

Comment: @dirojas I should have been clearer: the expectation is that your edit seems seamless into your question. Basically the edit should look like your question had been asked that way all along. People aren't here to learn how the question evolved to be what it is now, they are either looking to answer, or have a similar problem. In neither case is the evolution of the question important for that to be done :).